# laravel 5.3 cashier with stripe how to get remaining days to expire a plan

Tags: laravel-5.3, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.3 to subscribe users on plans with payment handling by stripe. I registered a plan on stripe, and subscribed user to that plan successfully using the following code

```
$user->newSubscription($planName, $planNameOnStripe)->create($creditCardToken);
```

Now the user is subscribed but how can I get the remaining days that user has left in that plan to expire. The users table, subscriptions table and the subscription object don't have any information about the expiry date or number of days.

Comment: please read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cashier-add-trial-end-date-when-creating-a-subscription?page=1

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate @JewelFarazi your efforts for me, but this link has nothing about obtaining the remaining days of a plan.

Comment: I need to know the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, is that without cancelling, the plan has no expiry. The expiry is populated only once the plan has been cancelled. This is because the whole concept of subscription is for it to be reoccurring.

However, if it is a cancelled plan, you can get the expiry by doing the following:

```
$user->subscription('main')->ends_at->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: what if we add extra column in subscriptions table and save expiry date there by getting from stripe while subscribing? we can get expiry date from stripe using `Auth::user()->subscription('main')->asStripeSubscription()->current_period_end`

Comment: @AfrazAhmad the `current_period_end` is the `timestamp` of next reccur (where payment is Invoiced automatically), not expire date.

Comment: (Hence `Auth::user()->subscription('myPlanName')->asStripeSubscription()->current_period_end` is useless for this task.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2022), neither `Cashier` nor `Stripe` API provide a *direct* way of getting an "expire-date" (i.e. a date from which point on the User is no longer considered a subscriber).

> I was looking here for the "Cashier way" of doing this, and will share the result.

Having that said, here is how I *indirectly* achieved it:

```php
// Load.
$subscription = Auth::user()->subscription('myPlanName');
$price = \Stripe\Price::retrieve(
    $subscription->stripe_price
);

// Parse from "interval" to duration (in days).
$duration = $price->recurring['interval_count'];
switch ($price->recurring['interval']) {
case 'day':
    break;
case 'week':
    $duration *= 7;
    break;
case 'month':
    $duration *= 30;
    break;
case 'year':
    $duration *= 365;
    break;
}

// At last, convert duration to expire-date.
$stripeObj = $subscription->asStripeSubscription();
$startTime = \max($stripeObj->start_date, $stripeObj->trial_end);
$expireDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($startTime)
    ->addDays($duration);
```

> **Note** that `stripe_price` is for me never `null`, but if you have multiple `subscription_items`, then you need to change above logic (because each `Price` *can* have it's own "`interval`" and "`interval_count`", in other words a separate "expire-date").
>
> **Downgrade:** In older Cashier versions (12.x and below), the `column` had `stripe_plan` as name (instead of `stripe_price` name), and you may need to use `\Stripe\Plan` class (instead of `\Stripe\Price`).
>
> See also [Revert renaming Plans to Prices (fix request)](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/issues/1341)